# ¿Para qué sirven los trait en PHP?

Tags: php, php7

Estoy usando `trait` en `PHP,` pero no sé cuál es su función útil. He mirado en la página oficial de `PHP` y otras páginas que hablan sobre estos, y sigo sin verle la utilidad. ¿Alguien me podría explicar para qué se usan? Gracias.

Comment: [Está muy bien explicado y ejemplificado aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.traits.php). ¿Qué es lo que no entiendes?

Comment: Básicamente, para simular una herencia múltiple. Permite dotar a una o varias clases de una serie de funcionalidades adicionales que no estén implementadas en la propia clase o clases de las que hereda.

Comment: @A.Cedano era la respuesta que me ha dado Orici. No entendía para qué se pueden usar, gracias por la respuesta.

Answer (score 3):

Los traits son como lo que en otros lenguajes se conoce como mixin.

Si tienes un proyecto destinado a manejar una fábrica, muchas de tus entidades (insumos, productos, pedidos, pagos, despachos, clientes) tendrán un CRUD (Create Read Update Delete). En un enfoque tradicional, podrías hacer que todos esos controllers heredasen de un controller genérico (CrudController) que sólo haga esas cuatro operaciones.

```
- CrudController
    └ InsumosController
    └ ProductosController
    └ PedidosController
    └ PagosController
    └ DespachosController
    └ ClientesController
```

Pero ahora resulta que las clases o controllers de Productos e Insumos tienen métodos para operar sobre el stock, que no aplican a despachos ni clientes. De nuevo, puedes hacer que esos dos hereden de un controller que implementa control de stock (StockController) y hereda de CrudController. A la larga tienes un árbol de herencia que se vuelve confuso de mantener.

```
- CrudController
    └ StockController
       └ InsumosController
       └ ProductosController
    └ PedidosController
    └ PagosController
    └ DespachosController
    └ ClientesController
```

Y finalmente llegas a implementaciones en donde controllers que no pueden heredar de los mismos padres. Por ejemplo productos, pagos y despachos pueden tener un estado (creado, en proceso, terminado) que ya no puedes meter a través de simple herencia. Ahí lo que corresponde es crear un Trait que les de esa funcionalidad.

```
trait HandleEstado {
  public function setEstado($estado) {
     $this.estado = $estado;
     $this.persist()  <--- este método viene de CrudController
  }
  public function getEstado() {
     return $this.estado;
  }
}
```

Y usar eso como

```
class ProductosController extends StockController {
  use HandleEstado;
  ...
}

class PagosController extends CrudController {
  use HandleEstado;
  ...
}
```

Finalmente, puedes tener clases que no son Crontrollers sino, por ejemplo, middlewares, modelos del ORM, factorías de objetos polimórficos, pero tú quieres darle a todo la posibilidad de escribir en los logs. De nuevo, ahí lo correcto sería permitirles usar un Trait o muchos que permitan acceder a todas las funcionalidades genéricas que sean oportunas:

```
trait Logger {

   public static_function log(string $message) {
      error_log( sprintf('%s dice: %s', __CLASS__, $message));
   }

 }

class PagosController extends CrudController {
  use HandleEstado,Logger;
  ...
  public function cursarPago($monto) {
      try {
        if($monto != $this->monto) {
          throw new Exception('El monto no corresponde!');
        }
        $this->setEstado('pagado');
        $this->persist();
      } catch (\Exception $e) {
        self::log($e->getMessage());
      }
  }
}
```